# How to maximize charging power to an external battery at the lowest cost

Tags: battery-charging

I am designing a system that contains the following:

1. An intermittent power source (nominally 20 W).
2. A box containing a buck converter under the control of a microcontroller. The converter output adjustable, but nominally 12 V and 1~2 A.
3. A second box containing a battery that the user can swap out.  Right now, it's a 12 V/8 Ah sealed AGM lead-acid battery, but I would like to be able to support other chemistries as well.
4. The system operates in a humid environment, so all connections are using IP67 or better sealed connectors.

The output of the converter in the first box goes through several connectors and cables into the battery in the second box to charge it.

Power is not always available so, ideally, whenever excess power is available, I want to put as much of it as I can into the battery. This means increasing the converter output current as much as I can without violating the maximum allowed voltage on the battery and destroying electrolyte.

I can measure the voltage and current at the output of the switching converter, but because all the cables, connectors, and fuses have resistance, the voltage at the battery will actually be lower by a few tenths of a volt. I suspect this problem occurs at some level in almost any battery charger, it's just particularly bad when the battery is in a separate box with a long cable and fuses between.

So, the question is then, how I maximize power output without destroying the battery at the lowest cost?

I see a few options:

1. Use a voltage at the source which is less than the maximum allowed by the battery. That guarantees never to harm the battery, but can result in very slow charge times, and potentially doesn't maximize charging power.
2. Use a higher charging voltage/current without really having a precise measurement of voltage at the battery itself, and then accept some electrolyte loss and shorter battery life. Not really desirable due to increased maintenance costs.
3. Characterize the system (measure the cable resistance on some units), and then knowing the current and resistance, estimate the actual voltage at the battery. Better than options 1 and 2, but as the system ages the resistances are likely to increase and result in poorer performance over time.
4. Use a large enough wire gauge in the cables that the voltage drop becomes negligible. The charging current is only like 1~2 A and the cables will be 10 ft max, so using like 10~12 AWG might accomplish that. The downside is that a 4-pin sealed connector with 10 AWG contacts is significantly more expensive than one with 4 x 20 AWG contacts.
5. Put in two extra kelvin sense wires in the cable. At a minimum I plan to use a 4-pin connector (2 power leads, and 2 for a thermistor). I could go to a 6-pin connector and add in the extra wires, but at a higher cost per connector.
6. Locate the battery in the same box as the charger. Now there are fewer cables and connectors to worry about, and almost no voltage drop. It's also cheap. But now the user can't swap out the battery very easily. Before they could just plug in a new one by screwing in the circular connector.
7. Use the 4-pin connector, and some sort of clever algorithm that periodically measures output voltage and current at a few different points to either determine the cable resistance or when I am destroying electrolyte. If anyone knows of one, I would like to hear it.

Are there any other options I am missing?

Comment: Your buck converter will need to be adjusted up to at least 14V or so to charge the battery properly.

Comment: Don’t put leadacid batteries in IP67 enclosures unless you want a bomb. The battery enclosures must he vented.

Comment: @Kartman A one-way vent can be added.

Answer (score 0):

Sense wires are a win.  If the connector is near the battery, the sense wires don't need to go through the connector.  They just have to be near enough to the battery for *voltage drop* to be not an issue.

On the other hand, if you know the wire size+length, and the amperage, then you also know the voltage drop.